unable to extract json column data (posgres 9.6)
I can run below query to get the data in given format as:
SELECT to_timestamp(unnest(ARRAY[[1725042600, 1725043500], [1725041700, 1725042600], [1725043500, 1725044400], [1725040800, 1725041700]]));

      to_timestamp
------------------------
 2024-08-30 18:30:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:45:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:15:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:30:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:45:00+00
 2024-08-30 19:00:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:00:00+00
 2024-08-30 18:15:00+00
(8 rows)

I am using postgres version 9.6 and below is schema
test_database=> \d fact_completeness_count_requests
                    Table "public.fact_completeness_count_requests"
         Column          |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 request_id              | character varying(64)       |           | not null |
 event_type              | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
 technology              | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 vendor                  | character varying(255)      |           |          |
 name                    | character varying(255)      |           | not null |
 dataset_metadata        | json                        |           | not null |

I am using below query to genrate the expected output. As shown in query output above. Not sure how to use array and to_timestamp function with below query. Is it possible to archive with postgres 9.6 version
select 
 request_id
,dataset_metadata->> 'intervals_epoch_seconds' as epoc_seconds
from fact_completeness_count_requests ;

 31319ad1-e848-4ec3-9c3e-967981e2ae45-0  | [[1725048000, 1725051600]]
 7a05cc38-5303-417d-88ce-fe3a604570d2    | [[1725055200, 1725056100]]
 ae6c2b09-8a95-4ac0-9846-6e76071579af    | [[1725050700, 1725051600], [1725049800, 1725050700], [1725048900, 1725049800], [1725048000, 1725048900]]


I am a little unsure what you want as result , can you add create table and insert into for the table and wanted result

unnest() returns all elements of an array, no matter the nesting level. There is no immediate counterpart for a JSON array, not even in current Postgres versions (Postgres 16 at the time of writing).
One path to a solution is to convert the JSON array to a Postgres array and then apply the simple power of unnest().
Postgres 10 or later
SELECT t.request_id, to_timestamp(unnest(j.intervals_epoch_seconds)) AS ts
FROM   fact_completeness_count_requests t
     , json_to_record(t.dataset_metadata) AS j(intervals_epoch_seconds float[]);

fiddle
The applicable variant of to_timestamp() takes float as input, so coerce the output from json_to_record() to float[] right away.
Postgres 9.6
The above fails in Postgres 9.6. Quoting the release notes of Postgres 10:


Make json_populate_record() and related functions process JSON arrays and objects recursively (Nikita Glukhov)
With this change, array-type fields in the destination SQL type are
properly converted from JSON arrays, and composite-type fields are
properly converted from JSON objects. Previously, such cases would
fail because the text representation of the JSON value would be fed to
array_in() or record_in(), and its syntax would not match what
those input functions expect.



A hackish workaround is to cast the array literal after manually exchanging delimiters [] to Postgres array delimiters {}:
SELECT request_id
     , to_timestamp(unnest(translate(dataset_metadata ->> 'intervals_epoch_seconds', '[]', '{}')::float[])) AS ts
FROM   fact_completeness_count_requests;

fiddle
There are many ways how this can break, if the JSON input does not match the given format.
Related:

How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?

Plus, the ancient Postgres 9.6 has more ways to confuse you. See:

What is the expected behavior for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?


Easiest way I found to extract any data from json is to use json_to_record.
select request_id, attempt, intervals_epoch_seconds[attempt:attempt][1:2] interval, to_timestamp(intervals_epoch_seconds[attempt][1]) startdate, to_timestamp(intervals_epoch_seconds[attempt][2]) enddate , to_timestamp(intervals_epoch_seconds[attempt][2]) -  to_timestamp(intervals_epoch_seconds[attempt][1]) attempt_duration
from (select '31319ad1-e848-4ec3-9c3e-967981e2ae45-0' request_id, '{"intervals_epoch_seconds":[[1725048000, 1725051600]]}'::json dataset_metadata
            union all
            select '7a05cc38-5303-417d-88ce-fe3a604570d2' request_id, '{"intervals_epoch_seconds":[[1725055200, 1725056100]]}'::json dataset_metadata
            union all
            select 'ae6c2b09-8a95-4ac0-9846-6e76071579af' request_id, '{"intervals_epoch_seconds":[[1725050700, 1725051600], [1725049800, 1725050700], [1725048900, 1725049800], [1725048000, 1725048900]]}'::json dataset_metadata
        ) mydataset
inner join json_to_record(dataset_metadata) as t(intervals_epoch_seconds int[]) on true
inner join generate_subscripts(intervals_epoch_seconds,1) attempt on true; 


This fails in Postgres 9.6. Would need at least Postgres 10 where json_to_record() and friends process JSON arrays recursively. Postgres 9.6 issues an error ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[[1725048000, 1725051600]]" DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.  because it naively expects array dimensions after a leading '[' in the array literal. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011569/939860
